# Can Java RegEx Parse These Type Strings?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use Java's Pattern & Matcher classes to parse out either a phone # or email from a string:

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(  "(.*):(\\s*)(.*)(\\s.*)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(parties);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        return matcher.group(3);
        //group(2) matches friendly name in Parties string
    }
```

It's close to working but not quite matching in all cases. Here are some samples of what I need to parse:

Ex. 1 "From:  +19255551212  MARY- SUE" needs to return "+19255551212"

Ex. 2 "From:  someone@gmail.com " needs to return "someone@gmail.com"

Ex. 3 "To:  +1 (415) 233-1212 Sally" needs to return "+1 (415) 233-1212"

Currently, the above code seems close but not quite right. It returns:

Ex. 1: +19255551212  MARY-

Ex. 2: someone@gmail.com

Ex. 3: +1 (415) 233-1212

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Regex is not suitable for parsing phone numbers nor email addresses. Can you use a library like libphonenumber?

Comment: `close but not quite right` what's not right about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your given examples this regex should work:

```
^(?:From|To):\s+(\+?[()\d\s-]*\d+|[^\s@]+@\S+)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9oQMw/1)

Though keep in mind that phone numbers and email addresses can vary a lot and this regex may need to be tweaked further depending on your inputs.